# How to display a JSON value in html value as it is using angularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

```
$scope.categories = [ {
      "advertiser_id": "2",
      "tier_id": 1,
      "tier_name": "1",
      "base_cpm_price": "",
      "retarget_cpm": "",
      "gender": "",
      "location": "",
      "ageblock1": "",
      "ageblock2": "",
      "ageblock3": "",
      "ageblock4": "",
      "ageblock5": "",
      "default": 1,
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "advertiser_id": "2",
      "tier_id": 2,
      "tier_name": "2",
      "base_cpm_price": "",
      "retarget_cpm": "",
      "gender": "",
      "location": "",
      "ageblock1": "",
      "ageblock2": "",
      "ageblock3": "",
      "ageblock4": "",
      "ageblock5": "",
      "default": 1,
      "status": 1
    },
    {
      "advertiser_id": "2",
      "tier_id": 3,
      "tier_name": "3",
      "base_cpm_price": 1,
      "retarget_cpm": 1,
      "gender": 1,
      "location": 1,
      "ageblock1": 10,
      "ageblock2": 0,
      "ageblock3": 0,
      "ageblock4": 0,
      "ageblock5": 0,
      "default": 0,
      "status": 1
    }
  ];
```

I have a 3 JSON object which i want to display in a HTML view using anjularJS.
But when im trying to display in HTML 0 value is considering as empty.

```
<tr ng-repeat="defaultsettings in listDefaultsettings >
   <td>{{defaultsettings.tier_name }}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.base_cpm_price || '---'}}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.retarget_cpm || '---'}}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.gender || '---'}}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.location || '---'}}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock1 || '---'}}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock2 || '---'}}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock3 || '---'}}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock4 || '---'}}</td>
   <td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock5 || '---'}}</td>
   <td class="td-active default-pricing">
</tr>
```

[image]

In place of 0 its replacing with --- but i want to display the value ie 0.

Comment: because in javascript `0` if falsy.

Comment: So how can i resolve this issue @Jai

Comment: `expr >= 0 ? expr : "---"` should do that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Because in javascript `0` is falsy.

```js
console.log(0||1);
console.log(""||"abc");
console.log(undefined||"defined");
console.log(null||"notnull");
```

---

To solve the issue you might get in with ternary if/else operation with `angular.isNumber()/angular.isString()` methods this way:

```
// define a method which returns a value
$scope.isEmptyValue = function(val, dashes){
  return (angular.isNumber(val) || !angular.isString(val)) ? val : dashes;
};
```

Now in the view you can do this:

```
<td>{{ isEmptyValue(defaultsettings.prop, "---") }}</td>
```

[Checkout this at plnkr.](https://plnkr.co/edit/c9P9O8I2a1s9hsZaKOys?p=preview)

Comment: Its working.. 0 is displaying but for empty values --- is not displaying :(

Comment: @PuneethKumar just add one or condition too for the empty values.

Comment: `<td> {{(defaultsettings.retarget_cpm >= 0 || defaultsettings.retarget_cpm != "") ? defaultsettings.retarget_cpm : '---'}} </td>` im using the above code but same issue.. not able to display ---...plz help me @jai

Answer (score 0):

Modify your td's using terenary operator to check existence of the value. If it is not present, only then print ---

```
   <td>{{(defaultsettings.retarget_cpm != null || defaultsettings.retarget_cpm !== "") ? defaultsettings.retarget_cpm : '---'}}</td>
```

Comment: Its working.. 0 is displaying but for empty values --- is not displaying :(

Answer (score 0):

replace the condition to check for a better falsy value. (i believe you are using `""` as a falsy value here)

```html
<tr ng-repeat="defaultsettings in listDefaultsettings >
<td>{{defaultsettings.tier_name }}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.base_cpm_price===""?defaultsettings.base_cpm_price : '---'}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.retarget_cpm===""?defaultsettings.retarget_cpm: '---'}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.gender===""?defaultsettings.gender : '---'}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.location===""?defaultsettings.location : '---'}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock1===""?defaultsettings.ageblock1 : '---'}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock2===""?defaultsettings.ageblock2 : '---'}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock3===""?defaultsettings.ageblock3 : '---'}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock4===""?defaultsettings.ageblock4 : '---'}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock5===""?defaultsettings.ageblock5 : '---'}}</td>
<td class=" td-active default-pricing ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a filter for the same

```
angular.module("my_module_name").filter('ignoreZeroAsFalse', ignoreZeroAsFalse);

function ignoreZeroAsFalse() {
    return filterDefinition;

    function filterDefinition(input) {
        return (input || input === 0)? input : '---'; 
    }

}
```

And your html will become like following

```
<td>{{defaultsettings.base_cpm_price | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.retarget_cpm | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.gender | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.location | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock1 | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock2 | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock3 | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock4 | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
<td>{{defaultsettings.ageblock5 | ignoreZeroAsFalse}}</td>
```